# jQuery 1 minute countdown with milliseconds and callback

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm trying to figure out a way to display a simple countdown that displays 1:00:00 whereby 1 = minutes, 00 = seconds, and 00 = milliseconds.

I've found loads of jQuery countdowns on the interwebs, but none of the contain the ability to display milliseconds natively, and I really don't want to dig through thousands of lines of code to try and find a way to hack it in there myself.

Is this something that would be pretty easy to whip up?

I'm also hoping to have the ability to add a callback to the end of the countdown (0:00:00) so that when it finishes, I can run another function.

Comment: From the number format, this looks more like *centiseconds* (100 centiseconds == 1 second), not *milliseconds* (1000 milliseconds == 1 second).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is going to sound a bit off the cuff, but if you make a small animated GIF that runs through ten random sets of two digits ten times a second, your users will never know the difference, and you won't have to worry about what you're going to do to your CPU load by trying to count down milliseconds in a web page.

Comment: I found a way to do it, and you were absolutely right... Adding milliseconds nearly KILLED my computer. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys I have developed a code for my self use the following code counter for 20 seconds

```
var _STOP =0;

var value=1999;

function settimer()

{
var svalue = value.toString();

if(svalue.length  == 3)

    svalue = '0'+svalue;
else if(svalue.length  == 2)
    svalue = '00'+svalue;
else if(svalue.length  == 1)
    svalue = '000'+svalue;
else if(value == 0)
    svalue = '0000';
document.getElementById('cn1').innerHTML = svalue[0];
document.getElementById('cn2').innerHTML = svalue[1];
document.getElementById('cn3').innerHTML = svalue[2];
document.getElementById('cn4').innerHTML = svalue[3];   
value--;

if (_STOP==0 && value>=0) setTimeout("settimer();", 10);
}

setTimeout("settimer()", 10);
```