# javascript countdown with showing milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, countdown

I want to do a count down and want to show like format as Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds. I made a count down with jquery plug-in [countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) but it shows just Minutes:Seconds format.
Is there any way to make it right?
Many Thanks!

Comment: If you want to show a countdown that updates _every single millisecond_, you're going to start hampering the browser's performance. Browsers generally won't even run `setTimeout`/`setInterval` this quickly. But hey - [see for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/q6tQT/).

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys I have developed a code for my self use the following code
counter for 20 seconds

```
var _STOP =0;

var value=1999;

function settimer()

{
    var svalue = value.toString();

    if(svalue.length  == 3)

        svalue = '0'+svalue;
    else if(svalue.length  == 2)
        svalue = '00'+svalue;
    else if(svalue.length  == 1)
        svalue = '000'+svalue;
    else if(value == 0)
        svalue = '0000';
    document.getElementById('cn1').innerHTML = svalue[0];
    document.getElementById('cn2').innerHTML = svalue[1];
    document.getElementById('cn3').innerHTML = svalue[2];
    document.getElementById('cn4').innerHTML = svalue[3];   
    value--;

    if (_STOP==0 && value>=0) setTimeout("settimer();", 10);
}

setTimeout("settimer()", 10);
```

Comment: You should not pass strings to setTimeout.  That involves an explicit call to `eval`.  Rather, you should pass a reference.  I.e., `setTimeout(settimer)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/TaHtz/76/

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

​
JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('timer');
var milliSecondsTime = 10000;
var timer;


el.innerHTML = milliSecondsTime/1000;
timer = setInterval(function(){
    milliSecondsTime = milliSecondsTime - 1000;
    if(milliSecondsTime/1000 == 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        el.innerHTML = 'BOOOOM';
    }
    else {
        el.innerHTML = milliSecondsTime/1000;
    }
},1000);
​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own timer.
read this earlier question 
[How to create a JQuery Clock / Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the format parameter - http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#format

On further reading, this plugin doesn't do milliseconds.  At this point, you either have to edit the actual plugin code or find a new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @Matt Ball's comment.It may also cause the browser to crash.

Why don't you  try this solution instead

[jQuery 1 minute countdown with milliseconds and callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020062/jquery-1-minute-countdown-with-milliseconds-and-callback)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this (generic counter from N to X (X > N)):

```
var dynamicCounterAddNewValue = 20;
    var currentDynamicUpdater;

    function dynamicCounterForValueForControlUpdater(_updaterData) {
       _updaterData.from += dynamicCounterAddNewValue;

       if (_updaterData.from > _updaterData.to) {
          _updaterData.from = _updaterData.to;
       }

       _updaterData.c.html(_updaterData.from.toString());
       if (_updaterData.from < _updaterData.to) {
          currentDynamicUpdater = setTimeout(
             dynamicCounterForValueForControlUpdater,
             10,
             {
                c: _updaterData.c,
                from: _updaterData.from,
                to: _updaterData.to
             }
             );
       }
       else {
          clearTimeout(currentDynamicUpdater);
       }
       return;
    }

    // _c -> jQuery object (div,span)
    // _from -> starting number
    // _to -> ending number
    function dynamicCounterForValueForControl(_c, _from, _to) {
       clearTimeout(currentDynamicUpdater);
       dynamicCounterForValueForControlUpdater(
          {
             c: _c,
             from: _from,
             to: _to
          }
          );
       return;
    }
```

EDIT: **Updated version** (more flexible - **for N elements one after another**):

(input element is *Array* of elements for making them dynamic-counts)

```
var dynamicCounterTimeout = 10;
var currentDynamicUpdater;

function odcArray(_odca) {
   this.odca = _odca;
   return;
}

function odc(_c, _from, _to) {
   this.c = _c;         // $('#control_id')
   this.from = _from;   // e.g. N
   this.to = _to;       // e.g. M => (M >= N)
   var di = parseInt(_to / 45, 10);
   if (di < 1) {
      di = 1;
   }
   this.dynamicInc = di;
   return;
}

function dynamicCounterForValueForControlUpdater(_odca) {
   if (
      _odca.odca === null
      ||
      !_odca.odca.length
      ) {
      clearTimeout(currentDynamicUpdater);
      return;
   }

   var o = _odca.odca[0];
   o.from += o.dynamicInc;

   if (o.from > o.to) {
      o.from = o.to;
      _odca.odca.shift();  // Remove first element
   }
   o.c.html(o.from.toString());

   currentDynamicUpdater = setTimeout(
      dynamicCounterForValueForControlUpdater,
      dynamicCounterTimeout,
      _odca
      );

   return;
}

function dynamicCounterForValueForControl(_odca) {
   clearTimeout(currentDynamicUpdater);
   // SETUP all counters to default
   for (var i = 0; i < _odca.odca.length; i++) {
      _odca.odca[i].c.html(_odca.odca[i].from.toString());
   }
   dynamicCounterForValueForControlUpdater(
      _odca
      );
   return;
}
```